# Is it possible to implement a Stack in Processing 3?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, processing

```
import java.util.Stack;
Stack stack = new Stack();

void setup(){
    stack.push('1');
    println(stack);
}
```

IDE says: "the function push(String) does not exist"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>(); stack.push("1"); @lisichka ggg

Comment: @AK.Sharma now it says that "Stack is not generic, it can not be parameterized with <String>

Comment: @luk2302 this is not the same as java, so I think this is why it's not working(

Comment: @lisichkaggg, Will suggest you to improve your question by adding more code.

Comment: @lisichkaggg, Is there another Stack data structure created by you in same package?

Comment: i didn't make any changes in the package, I am just using IDE from [link](http://processing.org)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine.

```
import java.util.Stack;
Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.push("1");
println(stack);
```

Notice that I've changed the `'1'` to a `"1"`, which I'm guessing is what you're actually doing.

This correctly prints out `[1]` for me.

You might want to add generics:

```
import java.util.Stack;
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
stack.push("1");
println(stack);
```

This will guarantee that you only add `String` values to your `Stack`. But it should work fine without this as well.

My guess is you just forgot the `stack.` part:

```
push("1");
```

This will generate the error you mentioned. Fix this by adding `stack.` in front of the function.

In the future, please make sure that the code you post in your question is actually the code you're running.

Comment: what IDE do you use?

Comment: @lisichkaggg The Processing editor. What IDE are you using?

Comment: @lisichkaggg The code in your edit also works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

String in java are double quotes `"string"` instead of `'string'`.
Moreover I found that for me, following code is working
[[confirmation image here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W28gN.png)

```
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    stack.push('1');
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
```

So,probably reason of this could be generics.
As you know `java.util.Stack` is generic framework.
So will suggest you to use
`Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();`